# Delay in bullets

Tags: java

I made my character shoot but the amount of bullets he shoots is way too much. I'm trying to add a delay between bullets. I've tried this:

```
int shootTime = System.currentTimeMllis();

public void tick() {
    if(input.shoot && System.currentTimeMillis() - shootTime > 1000)
    {
        shootTime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        shots.addBullet(new Bullet(xPos, yPos + 50));
    } 
  ........
  ........
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid but this is not working.

Comment: currentTimeMillis() returns a long and i don't think it'll fit in a int.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29664/adding-a-short-delay-between-bullets?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentTimeMllis` returns a `long` for the number of milliseconds *since Jan 7, 1970* (~1,425,579,434,000 at the time of this post!), not an `int` since program start, so that might be one problem.

Also, minor point of clarity, I'd suggest using something like:

```
long nextShot = 0;
long recoilTime = 1000;

public void tick() {
    if(input.shoot && System.currentTimeMillis() > nextShot)
    {
        nextShot = System.currentTimeMillis() + recoilTime;
        shots.addBullet(new Bullet(xPos, yPos + 50));
    } 
// ...
```

Comment: Optimizing away a subtraction... I'd like to see what kind of performance impact that makes :)

Comment: @jzx While introducing clarity you also changed logic, obscuring what said clarity is :)

Comment: Not really. `if((a-b)>c)` is much simpler than `if(a>b)`. Also, using a variable (`recoilTime`) instead of a constant number tells you what that number is for. It's a pattern at least as old as Quake - see nextThink http://www.moddb.com/groups/quakedb/tutorials/quake-c-think-and-nextthink.

Answer (score 1):

How many milliseconds since Jan 1 1970? About 1425579436439. That's more than fits in a integer. You need to use a `long`.